# how do I convert the function below into an arrow function

Tags: javascript

My question is how do I convert the function below into an arrow function?

```
onClick = {function(){model.clicks += 1; render(); }}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you really should read the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: `onClick = ((event) => { model.clicks += 1; render() });` Note just replace `function() {` with `() => {`

Answer (score 1):

```
const onClick = () => {model.clicks += 1; render(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this simple arrow function

```
const OnClick=()=>{
  model.clicks += 1;
  render(); 
}
```

with parameters:

```
const OnClick=({event})=>{
   console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Also, if the function has only a single parameter, you can omit the parentheses.